# Server returned HTTP response code: 500 (Worklight)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, worklight-server, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am getting HTTP response code: 500 in logs for wladmin user..because of this I am unable to deploy runtime for worklight console

```
[2/7/18 5:33:39:138 EST] 000000ab ServiceProxy  E   Received status 500 for GET https://localhost:9444/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
                             java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://localhost:9444/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Any help?

Error log:

```
NDIUtils     I   Resource conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context path is __globalscope__
[2/7/18 5:33:38:815 EST] 000000ad RuntimeServic E   Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.
There might be a JMX configuration error: null
[2/7/18 5:33:39:138 EST] 000000ab ServiceProxy  E   Received status 500 for GET https://localhost:9444/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
                             java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://localhost:9444/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1686)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1684)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1682)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1255)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:49)
at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:172)
at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet.service(ConsoleServicesServlet.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Comment: I don't see any evidence of "maximo", which is a separate product, in the description. Is it really part of this?

Comment: The log says "[2/7/18 5:33:38:815 EST] 000000ad RuntimeServic E   Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.".
JMX connection is required for admin to communicate with other components - runtime. This could be problem in your configuration or JNDI settings.